# Iterating three columns flexbox

Tags: html, reactjs, css, flexbox

I have a component in react which i, iterating in a loop. This component will always be shown three times and I want them to show in one single row (each component a column). The examples I have seen manually adds "flex:1;" and so on for every column, but since im iterating its not possible.

It looks like this:

```
<div className="styles.grid">
  <!-- stuff  -->
</div>
```

Above is going to be shown three times, and want them all in one single row (each going to be a column).

I have tried:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Does not work. Any help?

Comment: The `flex-wrap: wrap` would cause your row to break from one row, to multiple if the contents can't sit next to each other. Try removing that ?

Comment: Have you tried using `float: left`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `flex-wrap` to let all the flex items be on the same row, and give each flex item a third of the width.

**Example**

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="grid">
      <div className="grid-item item-1">Foo</div>
      <div className="grid-item item-2">Bar</div>
      <div className="grid-item item-3">Baz</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 33.33333%;
  height: 200px;
}
.item-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.item-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.item-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `flex-grow: 1` on the children columns. This tells the children to grow equally to fill their parents width.

For more info on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Below is a simple 3 column example, where each column expands equally.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
   flex-grow: 1;
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're probably trying to achieve:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: space-between;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item content</div>
</div>
```

Flex container will wrap every item, once it goes outside of its bounds with `flex-wrap: wrap;` property.

And every item inside the flex should then be set to `width: 30%;`. Every 4th item in grid will be wrapped to the next row.